# Composition Relationship

Tags: java

I have a composition relationship as follows. SubClass uses a method of MainClass. So it needs the reference of MainClass. Doing like that, `SubClass` is strongly tied to `MainClass`. Is it advisable to do so? Is there a way/design pattern to break cross dependency?

```
Public Class MainClass {

   private SubClass subClass;

   public MainClass(){

      subClass=new SubClass(this);

   }

   public doTCPCall(){
       ....
   }


}


Public Class SubClass {

   private MainClass mainClass;

   public SubClass(MainClass mainClass){

      this.mainClass=mainClass;

   }

   public doTCPCall(){
      mainClass.doTCPCall();
   }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything without more details. Try to expand the example code a bit. Where is the method from `MainClass` called and why does `SubClass` need it? Does subclass need to be tied to a specific instance of `MainClass` or any instance will do?

Comment: I updated the post. `SubClass` calls `doTCPCall` from `MainClass`. It isn't necessarily be tied to a specific instance of `MainClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method `MainClass.doTCPcall()` does not depend on any specific `MainClass` instance information to run, it could be made `static`. This way, `SubClass` would not need to store an instance of `MainClass`. It could just call the static method:

```
public void doTCPCall() {
    // Call the doTCPCall() using the class name instead of an instance
    MainClass.doTCPCall();
}
```